# COUNTIF for rows which contain a given value in another column

Tags: countif, libreoffice-calc

My table lists every character from all 5 of George R. R. Martin's currently published A Song of Ice and Fire novels. Each row contains a record indicating which book in the series the character is from (numbered 1-5) and a single letter indicating the character's gender (M/F). For example:

```
   A                  B     C
1  Character          Book  Gender
   ------------------------------
2  Arya Stark        -  1  -  F
3  Eddard Stark      -  1  -  M
4  Davos Seaworth    -  2  -  M
5  Lynesse Hightower -  2  -  F
6  Xaro Xhoan Daxos  -  2  -  M
7  Elinor Tyrell     -  3  -  F
```

I can use `COUNTIF` to find out that there are three females and three males in this table, but I want to know, for example, how many males there are in book 2. How could I write a formula that would make this count? Here is a pseudocode of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
=COUNTIF(C2:C7, Column B = '2' AND Column C = 'M')
```

This would output `2`.

I'm aware that this task is far better suited to databases and a `SELECT` query, but I'd like to know how to solve this problem within the constraints of a LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet, without using a macro. Excel-based solutions are fine, so long as they also work in Calc. If there's no solution that uses `COUNTIF`, it doesn't matter, so long as it works.

Comment: In Excel you have countifs (with an 's') to include more than one condition but I don't know if there is an equivalent in LibreOffice...

Comment: Yes, it turns out there is. I think I might have the solution using this formula...

Comment: Great, that works. Feel free to post that as an answer if you want some rep, or I'll put it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I worked it out, thanks to a prompt by assylias. The `COUNTIFS` formula produces the result I want by counting multiple search criteria. For example, this formula works out how many male characters are in Book 1 (A Game of Thrones).

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$2102, "=1", $L$2:$L$2102, "=M")
```

Comment: You should accept your own solution so this question is tagged as Answered. It'll encourage other people to look in and learn as well :)

Comment: I know, it said I had to wait 2 days to accept my own answer :/

Comment: For the record, COUNTIFS was added in LibreOffice 4.0